# Groups with sum zero don't show up

Tags: t-sql

I need to select weekly report (income for every week per every task type). For some weeks for which there is no entries with some task type I want to print 0 as income, but those groups don't show up in my select. #weeks is temp table which contains all weeks I want to have report for. What should I modify in my query?

```
SELECT weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, task.TaskId, task.Abbreviation, task.Name, COALESCE(SUM([entry.Income]), 0) AS IncomePerWeek 
FROM Task task 
LEFT JOIN Entry entry
ON task.TaskId = entry.TaskId 
INNER JOIN #weeks weeks 
ON entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate 
AND weeks.EndDate
GROUP BY weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, task.TaskId, task.Abbreviation, task.Name
ORDER BY weeks.BeginDate, task.Abbreviation
```

So I want result to look like this:

```
BeginDate    EndDate    TaskId    Abbreviation    Name    IncomePerWeek
----------------------------------------------------------------------
09/11/2015   15/11/2015  1        FT              First   15
09/11/2015   15/11/2015  2        ST              Second  0
...
```

So, for second task in week 09/11/2015 - 15/11/2015 there was no any entry in table Entry, but still I want to get row for that week and the task with IncomePerWeek = 0.

Answer (score 0):

its an inner join so both sides of the join must be present for a result.
if there are no entrys for that week in the entry table you wont get a result.

select from weeks full outer join tasks this will give you every combination of week and task. then left join entry on taskid and week. you've got the coalesce that 'converts' the nulls to 0s.

```
SELECT weeks.BeginDate,
 weeks.EndDate,
 task.TaskId,
 task.Abbreviation,
 task.Name,
 COALESCE(SUM([entry.Income]), 0) AS IncomePerWeek 
FROM #weeks weeks,  Task Task 
LEFT JOIN Entry entry
ON task.TaskId = entry.TaskId 
and entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate AND weeks.EndDate
GROUP BY weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, task.TaskId, task.Abbreviation, task.Name
ORDER BY weeks.BeginDate, task.Abbreviation
```

Comment: Then I get rows with weeks.BeginDate and weeks.EndDate null, which I don't want ofcourse.

Comment: what about selecting from weeks and joining tasks onto that.

Comment: so you have a week where there are no tasks of a given type and you want a 0?
you'll need to create a temp table of all the tasks and join that to your temp table of all the weeks.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that query exactly?   With the left join you should get all of #weeks.   Now you will get some null entry.EntryDate.

Comment: @pancho018, table Task contains all possible tasks. I edited question to be more clear.

Comment: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where boolean is expected", just before GROUP BY. Parenthesis around entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate AND weeks.EndDate doesn't change anything.

Comment: i think its a problem with the full outer join. try this latest version

Answer (score -1):

Try adding GROUP BY ALL to the query.

Comment: Result set remained completely same when I added group by all.